# Susy Gallery Center Last Row

Tags: susy

Using Susy 2 and trying to center the last row in the susy gallery. Interestingly enough I only have an odd number of logos needed to be displayed. 15 in total.  I tried just putting the last 3 in a separate div and messing with that but that seems like I'm adding more un-needed code. Any ideas? Many thanks in advance!

Here is a mixin I found on here awhile back for replacing the nth-omega function nixed from Susy 1:

```
@mixin nth-last($n, $type: child) {
&:nth-#{$type}(#{$n}) {
    @include last;
   }
}
```

I tried simply to just do span cols first

```
.partner {
   @include span(3 of 12);
   @include nth-last(4);   
}
```

then used the gallery

```
.partner {
   @include gallery(3);

}
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="logos">
     <div class="partner"><img src="images/partners/envestnet.jpg"/></div>
     <div class="partner"><img src="images/partners/guggenheim.jpg"/></div>
     <div class="partner"><img src="images/partners/usbancorp.jpg"/></div>
     <div class="partner"><img src="images/partners/advent.jpg"/></div>
     <div class="partner"><img src="images/partners/charles-schwab.jpg"/></div>
     <div class="partner"><img src="images/partners/bloomberg.jpg"/></div>
     <div class="partner"><img src="images/partners/stifel.jpg"/></div>
     <div class="partner"><img src="images/partners/pershing.jpg"/></div>
     <div class="partner"><img src="images/partners/credit-suisse.jpg"/></div>
     <div class="partner"><img src="images/partners/fidelity.jpg"/></div>
     <div class="partner"><img src="images/partners/sp.jpg"/></div>
     <div class="partner"><img src="images/partners/ultimus.jpg"/></div>
     <div class="partner"><img src="images/partners/hsg.jpg"/></div>
     <div class="partner"><img src="images/partners/deutsche-bank.jpg"/></div>
     <div class="partner"><img src="images/partners/interactive-brokers.jpg"/></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no good way to do centering with floats, so you'll need to use a different technique all together - either on the full list, or on the last three. My preference for this is using flexbox, but that excludes some older browsers. Another option might be using inline-block, but that comes with it's own challenges. In either case, there are no Susy mixins to do it for you, but you can use susy functions (`span` and `gutter`) to keep you aligned to the grid:

```
.logos {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.partner {
  width: span(3 of 12);
  margin-right: gutter(12);

  &:nth-child(4n),
  &:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok after seeing your suggestion I went with simply....

@include span(3 of 12);
margin-left: gutter(3);

Comment: That `margin-left: gutter(3)` is basically giving you an arbitrary number. You're asking Susy to give you a gutter width as though you are in a context of `3`, which you aren't. You really want to push it in a column and a half (in a context of `12`). It might work, but in that case Susy is making your code *less clear*.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled over the answer today and couldn't use flexbox for several reasons.
My solutions with `@gallery` seems to work well. I was even able to reset a previously created centering which seems necessary if you're adjusting the gallery sizes in media queries.

*NOTE: that i'm using [@breakpoint](https://github.com/at-import/breakpoint) in the following example:*

```scss
article {
    @include breakpoint($medium-up) {
        @include gallery(6 of 12);

        &:last-child:nth-last-child(2n + 1) {
            background-color: red;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            float: none;
        }
    }

    @include breakpoint($large-up) {
        @include gallery(4 of 12);

        &:last-child:nth-last-child(2n + 1) {
            background-color: green;
            margin-left: get-span-width(8 of 12 wide);
            margin-right: -100%;
            float: left;
        }
    }
}
```

I had some trouble figuring out how i could recalculate the given offset and after digging through the `gallery()` -> `get-isolation()` -> `get-span-width()` function of susy itself i was able to find it [here](https://github.com/oddbird/susy/blob/susytwo/sass/susy/language/susy/_span.scss#L149).

**EDIT:**

I've also found this [article](https://reformatcode.com/code/css/css-susy-gallery---center-last-row-with-nth-last-child) and [codepen](https://codepen.io/bennyb/pen/kXVaba) which can help too.